# Quiz django. Can't get answers to the questions

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-quiz

I'm new to django and I don't understand why the answers to the questions are not displayed on the screen (although the questions themselves are displayed). Everything is also empty in the source code of the page. Help please

model.py

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _


class people(models.Model):
    CHOICES_TEST_ID = (('0', 'КСС'),
                       ('1', 'Золотые правила'),
                       ('2', 'MWD'),
                       ('3', 'DD'))
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    test_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES_TEST_ID, default=0, blank=False)
    date_of_passage = models.DateField(_('Date'), auto_now_add=True)
    correct_answer = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    done = models.BooleanField('Тест сдан', default=False)

    def number_correct_answer(self):
        self.correct_answer += 1


class questions(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField('Вопрос', max_length=500, null=False)
    test_id = models.CharField('Идентификационный номер теста', max_length=2, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Вопросы'


class answers(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField('Ответ', max_length=200, null=False)
    true_answer = models.BooleanField('Правильный ответ', default=False)
    question = models.ForeignKey(questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ответы'
```

forms.py

```
from .models import people, answers
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, RadioSelect


class PeopleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = people
        fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'surname', 'test_id']
        widgets = {'firstname': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'firstname', 'placeholder': 'Ввод'}),
                   'lastname': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'lastname', 'placeholder': 'Ввод'}),
                   'surname': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'surname', 'placeholder': 'Ввод'}),
                   'test_id': RadioSelect()}


class AnswersForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = answers
        fields = ['answer', 'true_answer', 'question']
        widgets = {'true_answer': RadioSelect()}
```

views.py

```
import random
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import PeopleForm, AnswersForm
from django.core.cache import cache
from .models import questions, people


def first(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PeopleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cache.set('test_id', form.cleaned_data.get("test_id"))
            form.save()
            cache.set('id_people', people.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).last())
            return redirect('main')

    form = PeopleForm()

    data = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'main/first_page.html', data)


def random_questions(test_id):
    questions_all = questions.objects.filter(test_id=test_id).values_list('pk', flat=True)
    questions_selected = set()
    while len(questions_selected) != 3:
        questions_selected = questions_selected.union(set(random.sample(sorted(questions_all), 3)))
    selected_questions = questions.objects.filter(pk__in=questions_selected, test_id=test_id)
    return selected_questions


def main(request):
    test_id = cache.get('test_id')
    selected_questions = random_questions(test_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_main = AnswersForm(request.POST)
        if form_main.is_valid():
            correct = 0
            if form_main.cleaned_data.get('true_answer'):
                correct += 1
            id_people = cache.get('id_people')
            people.objects.filter(pk=id_people).update(correct_answer=correct)
            if correct == 3:
                return redirect('done')
            if correct != 3:
                return redirect('lose')

    else:
        form_main = AnswersForm()

    data = {'selected_questions': selected_questions,
            'form': form_main}

    return render(request, 'main/main_page.html', data)


def end_lose(request):
    id_people = cache.get('id_people')
    correct_answers = people.objects.filter(pk=id_people).values('correct_answer')
    return render(request, 'main/end_page_lose.html', {'correct_answers': correct_answers})


def end_done(request):
    id_people = cache.get('id_people')
    correct_answers = people.objects.filter(pk=id_people).values('correct_answer')
    return render(request, 'main/end_page_successfully.html', {'correct_answers': correct_answers})
```

main.html

```
{% extends 'main/base_page.html' %}

{% block title %}
Тестирование
{% endblock %}

{% block article %}

<article>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for question in selected_questions %}
            <h2>{{ question.question }}</h2>
            {% if form_main.question_id == question.id %}
                {{form_main.answer}}{{form_main.true_answer}}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Далее</button>
    </form>
</article>

{% endblock %}
```

I searched all similar problems and tried to do it differently. Unfortunately, the result is negative.
I am also considering the output of not all questions on one page, but alternately. But I can't figure out how to implement this, since I need unique questions in the amount of 15 out of the total number of questions

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your context. This is what you are passing:

```
data = {'selected_questions': selected_questions,
        'form': form_main}
```

And this you are trying to call:

```
{% if form_main.question_id == question.id %}
    {{form_main.answer}}{{form_main.true_answer}}
{% endif %}
```

You have to call by the key, because that's what Template engine is looking at from the context. So change ie. context to that:

```
data = {'selected_questions': selected_questions,
        'form_main': form_main}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to fix it in the question. 'form_main' was already there. unfortunately, that's not the problem. there are still no answers displayed there